# Usage of "it's to"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english, phrase-usage, literary-english

> When I finally wake up, it's to his arm slung over me, holding me close to his chest.

The sentence above is the extract of a reading source.

What possibly could be the meaning of "**it's to...**"?

How it could be used in other scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

One can wake up to a situation, meaning one wakes to discover that situation. I woke up to a snowstorm; he woke up to a cold house; when she woke up it was to his arm ... holding her. In your example, the present tense is used for immediacy.

Beware of a similar figurative usage. One can 'wake up to' a situation, meaning to suddenly realise that something is the case - I woke up to the fact that my husband had been cheating on me.

Comment: You can also open the door to a snowstorm, or turn on the TV to an unexpected news item, etc. I guess any situation where you do something that changes your perception or awareness of the world (wake up, open your eyes, turn on the radio, ...) Think of it as "to *find* ..."

Comment: Thanks! It really gives me some sense of better using this.